# jQuery Sortable applied to table rows makes rows taller

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm preparing a custom positioning for table rows with jQuery UI Sortable, but I've run into a major problem. Whenever I grab a row, it gains about `2px` height. However, the margin, height, padding etc. remain the same. I've created a test page, without any additional scripts or styles. Is here anything I can do to prevent this *rows getting taller* issue from happening? Thanks.

jQuery: 1.4.4, jQuery UI: 1.8.9

Edit: this happes in Chrome and Safari (haven't tested other browsers) on Mac. This very example on jsFiddle works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/yA47C/, but I'm not quite sure what could be different there.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>    
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr><th>header</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="sortable">
            <tr><td>row 1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>row 2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>row 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>row 4</td></tr>
            <tr><td>row 5</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table> 
    <script> 
    $(function() {
        $(".sortable").sortable();
    });
    </script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: This exact code works fine for me in Chrome 10.0.644.0 for Ubuntu. No extra padding appears as you describe. Not sure how this comment will help you -- just a data point in case it does.

Comment: same as @Ben Lee, here's a jsFiddle that demonstrates that: http://www.jsfiddle.net/jbenson/tpJjm/1/ Perhaps post your relevant stylesheet, might help or be the problem etc.  Edited, tested in FF/IE on Windows.

Comment: Does your css give a border to the selected element? In IE (haven't had to dev for chrome/safari recently) I know that adding a border will affect the height of the element due to the way IE applies the layers of padding, margin, and border. That the border is actually apart of the height. Might be the same implementation for yours as well.

Comment: I've tried it without any styles applied. It's slightly possible that my Chrome version has different the default styles or my extensions or apps changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the problem is (since this works for me), but if it works for you in jsfiddle, it's definitely one of those css rules in normalize.css that's fixing it for you:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/css/normalize.css

```
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset
input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}
fieldset,img { 
    border:0;
}
address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var {
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
}
ol,ul {
    list-style:none;
}
caption,th {
    text-align:left;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-size:100%;
    font-weight:normal;
}
q:before,q:after {
    content:'';
}
abbr,acronym { border:0;}
```

If I had to guess, I'd say it's the "table" rule. Could also be the "td" rule.

Comment: Thanks, it was really the `table`, actually the `border-spacing`.

Comment: @Mikulas, in that case, then if you care about it working in earlier versions of IE, then you should probably also add a `cellspacing="0"` attribute to the `<table>`. Early IE's had issues where only the attribute worked correctly, and it ignored the css rule.

Comment: Interesting, I will certainly add that rule. Thank you.

Comment: I was seeing the same problem (table row spacing increasing each time a row was dragged to a new position) while using jQuery v1.5.1 and jQueryUi v1.8.11 - seen on Chrome 19.0.1084.52. Changing `border-spacing: 0 5px` to  `border-spacing: 0` resolved the problem  (but also changed the layout of course).